# Can I disable xml-rpc by setting it to false?

Tags: plugins, php, security, xml-rpc

I've been searching about it and came across with this snippet code, will it disable safely the `xml-rpc`?

```php
// set below line to false in /public_html/xmlrpc.php 
...
define( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST', true );
...
```

### Update

I've installed and activated [Disable XML-RPC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-xml-rpc/) plugin, but the [wordpress security scanner](https://gf.dev/wordpress-security-scanner) still showing it is enabled!

[image]
(I'm newbie in wordpress/php code development )

### Update2

I've installed `wpscan` and just use it to test my web site and here is the result for `xml-rpc`:

```
[+] XML-RPC seems to be enabled: https://..../xmlrpc.php
 | Found By: Link Tag (Passive Detection)
 | Confidence: 100%
 | Confirmed By: Direct Access (Aggressive Detection), 100% confidence
 | References:
 |  - http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Pingback_API
 |  - https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/wordpress_ghost_scanner/
 |  - https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/dos/http/wordpress_xmlrpc_dos/
 |  - https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/wordpress_xmlrpc_login/
 |  - https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/wordpress_pingback_access/

[+] WordPress version 5.9 identified (Latest, released on 2022-01-25).
 | Found By: Rss Generator (Passive Detection)
 |  - https://..../feed/, <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=5.9</generator>
 |  - https://cafedx.com/comments/feed/, <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=5.9</generator>
```

Comment: that website should be considered an opinion rather than factual, XMLRPC was once a concern but that was a very very long time ago, more than 10 years ago, the advice is outdated, and might even break your site on some hosts. Likewise external WP Cron is not a security concern

Comment: Actually, there was an attack using xml-rpc on my website yesterday. I did change the wp-login address to a custom address, but the  attacker still can access login not via the url but via the xml-rpc. that's the reason why I need to disable it!

Comment: You should expect "attacks" on all your files, including Drupal files and Joomla files that don't exist on your site, and ASP.net and Node exploits. Moving and hiding things doesn't fix that. Look at wordpress.com the biggest WP install on the planet serving billions of visitors per day and hundreds of millions of registered users, and it still has the login in the same place, and XMLRPC is still reachable: https://wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php

Comment: Instead, enable 2 factor auth, and install some sort of limit login plugin to auto-ban after 3 or 4 failed attempts. If you can do it at the server level via Nginx/IPTables/Apache even better. Otherwise what you're doing does not improve security

Comment: I already did that by using limit login. But `multilayer/step` security is what I'm going to do right now...

Comment: I've ran this on my own site, and the results are... not great. Its recommendations are based on misunderstandings and out of date advice, as well as things that are plain wrong, e.g. recommending I upgrade from 5.8.1 to 5.8.3, when I actually run 5.9. That scanner site is not to be trusted

Comment: so I ran WP Scan CLI tool on my site directly which is what that scanner site is using, and it seems that any information WP Scan reports is being interpreted as a security issue, even if it's purely informational. This scanner tool is unable to distinguish the difference, combined with the misunderstandings and outdated security advice the site authors have included. What you are trying to do will reduce not improve security, you should not do it. The site is also not sharing the confidence values WP Scan outputs and assuming 100% confidence

Comment: I actually don't have any need for such a thing like xml-rpc. Is the proposed snippet a good solution to disable xml-rpc?